# SQL Connection String to SQL Server Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am having trouble trying to get my connection string to connect to my SQL Database file here is my code

```
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Dim sqlstring as string


    'Difines what database i would like to use '
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAREPOINT-TEST;AttachDbFilename=\\sharepoint-test\SPD\MSSQL\Data\ProblemsAndActions.mdf")
    'Opens the connection to the database'
    myConn.Open()
    'inserts into database what table and what information relevant to what variable line in table Master'
    sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Master (Id, Raised_By, Customer, Complainant_Details, Product_Code_Affected, Description_Of_Product, Qty_Affected, Batch_Affected, End_Customer, Order_Number, Consignment_Number, Details_Of_Complaint, Severity_Rating) VALUES ('" + L1 + "','" + L2 + "','" + L3 + "','" + L4 + "','" + L5 + "','" + L6 + "','" + L7 + "','" + L8 + "','" + L9 + "','" + L10 + "','" + L11 + "','" + L12 + "','" + L13 + "')"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn) 'comands to insert the above line ^'
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command'
    myConn.Close() 'closes connection to database'
```

Error I keep getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My SQL Server instance Name is *`SHAREPOINT-TEST\SHAREPOINTTESTSQ`*

Comment: Ports open in the firewall? Server set up to allow remote connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can execute that SQL using SSMS, I suspect that tour connection string is incorrect. Try:

```
myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=SHAREPOINT-TEST\SHAREPOINTTESTSQ;Database=ProblemsAndActions;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;")
```

Or more details at:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Hello Dd2, Thank you for your help but it seams to be now giving my a different error message ;Login Failed for User "sa"

Comment: I suppose you can connect via ssms with those credentials?!

Comment: Hello Dd2 Yes I can connect via ssms with these credentials

Comment: Are u using SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: @BennjaminMiles '*Login Failed for User "sa"*' Means that something else is going wrong.  If this login works in SSMS ("sa"+password), then use this to connect to the server with SSMS and check the SQL Server error logs.  They are under the "Management" folder and labelled "SQL Server Logs". Open the Current one and search for your login failure message.  Immediately before it in the log and with the same timestamp should be another message that looks like "**Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: <#>.**"  Find that state number and tell us what it is.

Comment: Hello RBarryYoung The state is 58

Comment: @BennjaminMiles OK, state 58 occurs when a SQL server login is used for accessing SQL server when SQL server is installed with windows authentication mode.  So check you server to see if it allows mixed mode authentication.  If not you either have to change that or switch to using Trusted (i.e, Windows) authentication.